# From a bit complex SQL statement to preparedStatement

Tags: sql, oracle

Hy, Im having trouble with sql, oracle..

```
SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA  FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE 
DATUM_OSIGURANJA = MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB;
```

My goal is to get only one row with highest value of date (DATUM_OSIGURANJA). 
How can I add an argument to this statement?
Argument should be OIB from table EVP_V_KASKO_ZB.
something like statement + WHERE OIB = ?;  so I can send this to POSTMAN and there find my values by argument, which is OIB.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Result is one model of a car, one production year of a car and date when the car is registered. Result is only one because my dates of registration are unique. I just need to find those results by OIB. (OIB is in Croatia ID of a person)
I must say -give me this results by OIB which i must write in POSTMAN program as argument
EDIT:  -using Oracle dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to limit this by OIB - so for a passed OIB, you want to get record(s) with max DATUM_OSIGURANJA.

Try using this:

SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA
FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB EVP_1
WHERE EVP_1.OIB = <>
AND DATUM_OSIGURANJA = (select MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE OIB = EVP_1.OIB)

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. You need a subquery, as in:

```
SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA  FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE 
DATUM_OSIGURANJA = (select MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB)
```

Comment: Suffice to say that this query will result in multiple rows, if there are multiple rows tied in first place.

Comment: It will be only one row because years in DATUM_OSIGURANJA are unique and with SELECT MAX i get the newest year. I just need to tell the program: - give me MODEL, V_GODINA AND DATUM_OSIGURANJA by the value OIB which I must post in POSTMAN program like argument